.NET Serializing a complex Dto to JSON string
I am working with a Dto Structure that looks like the following. I will omit information regarding other derived types as they are not part of the problem at hand. Take note that the OldValue and NewValue properties can actually be one of the many other Dto (Multi-Typed).
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ChangeBucketDto), "changeBucketDto")][JsonDerivedType(typeof(TrackedChangeDto), "trackedChangeDto")]
public class Dto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique identifier of the entity
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public required string Key { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeBucketDto : Dto
{
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public required string Text { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("changes")]
    public required List<TrackedChangeDto> Changes { get; set; }
}

public class TrackedChangeDto : Dto
{
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("origin")]
    public required ChangeOrigin Origin { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("oldValue")]
    public dynamic? OldValue { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("newValue")]
    public dynamic? NewValue { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("changeType")]
    public required string ChangeType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("displayOrder")]
    public required List<string> DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("lastModified")]
    public required DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("live")]
    public required bool Live { get; set; }
}

Using the JSON gained from the following function.
public async Task<ActionResult<dynamic>> WriteChangesAsJson(StorageEnvironment environment, [FromBody] List<ChangeBucketDto> json)
{
    return await WriteAllAsJson(environment, json);
}

I will try to serialize it into a Dto that can be used to process. The TDto type is derived from the controller that the service is referenced in which is configured at startup. This type is also mapped using AutoMapper to a corresponding Model.
async Task IStorageService<TDto>.WriteAllAsync(ConnectionPropertiesModel connectionProperties, dynamic json)
{
    try
    {
        string stringified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);

        // Write a new file content to the blob
        await _repository.WriteAsync(connectionProperties, jsonString:stringified);
    }
    catch (ConnectionPropertiesException connectionEx)
    {
        IError error = _errorFactory.CreateError(ErrorCode.ServiceNoAccess, _exceptionResourceManager.GetString("ServiceAccessExc")!);
        throw new ServiceAccessException(error, connectionEx);
    }
}

The resulting ChangeBucket array properly contains a TrackedChange object in the correct bucket, however the OldValue and NewValue will not contain the values of the corresponding Dto. Instead it will show ValueKind.
{
    "text": "Highlights",
    "changes": [
      {
        "origin": {
          "ContainerName": "highlights",
          "FileName": "highlights.json"
        },
        "oldValue": {
          "ValueKind": 1
        },
        "newValue": {
          "ValueKind": 1
        },
        "changeType": "Update",
        "displayOrder": [
          "key",
          "languages",
          "enabled",
          "repeat",
          "timeSpan",
          "timeStampFrom",
          "timeStampTo"
        ],
        "lastModified": "2024-05-13T14:13:11.629Z",
        "live": true,
        "key": "change-highlights-Maintenance"
      }
    ],
    "key": "highlights"
  },

EDIT: I realize now that there is a bit of a mix between System.Text.Json and NewtonSoft.Json that is causing the issue here. My end goal is to be able to read this object as a whole using exclusively one of these, but I'm not quite sure what I need to get there.
EDIT2: Per request I am including the full JSON for how a post to the change tracking controller could look like, including two examples of the Dto it could obtain.
[
  {
    "text": "Vragen",
    "changes": [],
    "key": "questions"
  },
  {
    "text": "Berichten",
    "changes": [
      {
        "origin": {
          "ContainerName": "answers",
          "FileName": "answers.json"
        },
        "oldValue": {
          "key": "Foo",
          "languages": [
            { "NL": "Bor" },
            { "EN": "Bar" }
          ],
          "type": "message"
        },
        "newValue": {
          "key": "Foo",
          "languages": [
            { "NL": "Bar" },
            { "EN": "Bar" }
          ],
          "type": "message"
        },
        "changeType": "Update",
        "displayOrder": [
          "key",
          "languages",
          "type"
        ],
        "lastModified": "2024-05-13T17:23:30.509Z",
        "live": true,
        "key": "change-highlights-Maintenance"
      }
    ],
    "key": "answers"
  },
  {
    "text": "FAQs",
    "changes": [],
    "key": "faqs"
  },
  {
    "text": "Dialogen",
    "changes": [],
    "key": "dialogs"
  },
  {
    "text": "Highlights",
    "changes": [
      {
        "origin": {
          "ContainerName": "highlights",
          "FileName": "highlights.json"
        },
        "oldValue": {
          "key": "Foo",
          "languages": [
            { "NL": "Bor" },
            { "EN": "Bar" }
          ],
          "enabled": "true",
          "repeat": "true",
          "timeSpan": 7,
          "timeStampFrom": "2023-12-13T11:50",
          "timeStampTo": "2023-12-13T17:00"
        },
        "newValue": {
          "key": "Foo",
          "languages": [
            { "NL": "Bar" },
            { "EN": "Bar" }
          ],
          "enabled": "true",
          "repeat": "true",
          "timeSpan": 7,
          "timeStampFrom": "2023-12-13T11:50",
          "timeStampTo": "2023-12-13T18:00"
        },
        "changeType": "Update",
        "displayOrder": [
          "key",
          "languages",
          "enabled",
          "repeat",
          "timeSpan",
          "timeStampFrom",
          "timeStampTo"
        ],
        "lastModified": "2024-05-13T17:23:30.509Z",
        "live": true,
        "key": "change-highlights-Maintenance"
      }
    ],
    "key": "highlights"
  },
  {
    "text": "Groepsincidenten",
    "changes": [],
    "key": "groupincidents"
  },
  {
    "text": "Kennisbanken",
    "changes": [],
    "key": "knowledgesources"
  }
]


I would try to avoid dynamic. If old/new value is one of several possible types, make sure types share a common base interface and use "JsonDerivedType". If old/new value can truly be any kind of object I would consider alternative solutions, since arbitrary object types will be very difficult to use.

Every time you use dynamic, a kitten dies. It's hard to tell exactly what you are doing here, or why you feel you need to use dynamic, but perhaps generics would be a better fit?

You are mixing attributes from different serializers.  JsonDerivedTypeAttribute is from System.Text.Json while JsonProperty is from Newtonsoft.Json.  Why are you doing that?

Instead it will show ValueKind -- that is because your dynamic property contains a JsonElement from System.Text.Json and you are trying to serialize it with Json.NET.  You cannot serialize DOM objects from one serializer using the other.  Why are you even trying?  Why not use one serializer consistently?

You guys have some fair points. There is some remnants from experimenting with either of the two, at first I tried with NewtonSoft exclusively but it failed to read anything on the level of the TrackedChangeDto. There is a few solutions, like ExpandoObjects, but I couldn't quite wrap my head around these yet.

@JonasH I did try an approach using JsonDerivedType however it resulted in the same issue as above. I'm not sure why, but I assume it's because the Dto is nested into another Dto.

@DavidG I did try an approach to implement generics, but due to the fact that both the service and repository itself already use generics, it would create some impossibilities for configuring the services.

@RK - Can you share the posted JSON that you are binding to your List<ChangeBucketDto> json?

dynamic would deserialize to JObject if you will use Newtonsoft, also you did not provided class for ChangeOrigin

@dbc I have included it in the post under Edit 2.
@PowerMouse I did not provide the class for ChangeOrigin as it is a struct with two values, and it does read this one properly.

you have broken json in  "languages": [
"NL": "Bor"
"EN": "Bar" areas

Your "full JSON" is malformed.  Upload it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will see multiple errors and warnings.  Is your actual input JSON malformed?  If so, you won't be able to use System.Text.Json or Json.NET to parse it.  But if it is well-formed please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] with real JSON.  Thanks!

@dbc whoops my bad, I added the examples by hand while eating and I forgot some bits.

You have the following problems here:

You are mixing attributes from System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.  E.g. JsonDerivedTypeAttribute is from System.Text.Json while JsonPropertyAttribute is from Newtonsoft.Json.
These serializers are not compatible, you cannot mix and match attributes from both.  I recommend you choose one and stick with it.

You are mixing Document Object Model objects from both serializers as well.  You declare your "oldValue" and "newValue" to be dynamic.  ASP.NET Core uses SystemText.Json for model binding, and for dynamic and object types this serializer deserializes JSON to JsonElement.  But Json.NET does not understand this type, which is why you are seeing its single property serialized: { "ValueKind": 1 }.

And in general I would recommend against using dynamic.  It leads you to think you are writing generally applicable code, but in fact you end up writing "psuedo-general" code that compiles successfully but contains all sorts of hidden assumptions and dependencies that only show up at runtime.


Since ASP.NET Core uses System.Text.Json for model binding, I would recommend you use it for serialization as well.  Modify your model as follows:
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ChangeBucketDto), "changeBucketDto"), JsonDerivedType(typeof(TrackedChangeDto), "trackedChangeDto")]
public class Dto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique identifier of the entity
    /// </summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("key")]
    public required string Key { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeBucketDto : Dto
{
    [JsonRequired]
    [JsonPropertyName("text")]
    public required string Text { get; set; }
    [JsonRequired]
    [JsonPropertyName("changes")]
    public required List<TrackedChangeDto> Changes { get; set; }
}

public class TrackedChangeDto : Dto
{
    [JsonRequired]
    [JsonPropertyName("origin")]
    public required ChangeOrigin Origin { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("oldValue")]
    public JsonNode? OldValue { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("newValue")]
    public JsonNode? NewValue { get; set; }
    [JsonRequired]
    [JsonPropertyName("changeType")]
    public required string ChangeType { get; set; }
    [JsonRequired]
    [JsonPropertyName("displayOrder")]
    public required List<string> DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    [JsonRequired]
    [JsonPropertyName("lastModified")]
    public required DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    [JsonRequired]
    [JsonPropertyName("live")]
    public required bool Live { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeOrigin
{
    [JsonPropertyName("ContainerName")]
    public string? ContainerName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("FileName")]
    public string? FileName { get; set; }
}

And you should be able to round-trip your JSON successfully:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
};
var stringified = JsonSerializer.Serialize(json, options);

Notes:

Remove all using Newtonsoft.Json namespace references from your code.
Replace [JsonProperty("name")] with [JsonPropertyName("name")].
You can use [JsonRequired] or just the required keyword to make System.Text.Json throw an error on a missing property.
I used JsonNode rather than dynamic to capture your free-form JSON.  If you have some POCO you would like to serialize to JsonNode you can do so with JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode().

Demo fiddle here.

Thank you for the information, I will give it a shot and let you know if it succeeded somewhere this week.

Your solution functions exactly as I needed, thank you very much for your patience and assistance.
